# Sending an Object over a network using Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I am trying to send an object in java over a physical network (not over localhost) but it seems I have something wrong.

The interface to the object (client and server have this):

```
public interface distributable extends Serializable {

      public void test();
}
```

The Object I am trying to send (only server has this):

```
class ObjectToSend implements distributable {

       public ObjectToSend() {
       }

       public void test() {
            system.out.println("worked!");
       } 
}
```

Server:

```
private ObjectToSend obj = new ObjectToSend();

obj_out_stream.writeObject(obj);
obj_out_stream.flush();
```

Client:

```
private distributable ReceivedObj = null;

try {
       ReceivedObj = (distributable) obj_in_steam,readObject();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       System.err.println("Error<w_console>: Couldn't recieve application code!");
} 
ReceivedObj.test();
```

Everything was working when the `ObjectToSend` class implemented Serializable and I wasn't using an interface because all my classes were in one directory so the client 'knew' about the object. Now I want it to work across a physical network so the client only has the interface to the object. It seems that client can not receive the object as the exception is thrown every time.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you know that a pencil is a writing instrument if you don't know what a pencil is. Sending an object of which you only know an interface for doesn't work because you still need to know what the object is. Interfaces are not a replacement for class definitions.

Comment: Note: Java classes' and interfaces' names should start with an uppercase letter. Also, your code is full of errors that mean you haven't really used it: fix it, try it again and add more details on the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers suggest, the Client also has to know the class of the object you want to send.

Usually, one creates three packages/projects for such a classic client-server example:

Common: Code that is used by client and server; the class definition of the objects you want to send from the server to the client belongs here

Client: All code only the client needs to know about

Server: All code only the server needs to know about

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be like this. What can you do with a class whose code you don't have?

Have a look here: stackoverflow.com/questions/8175052/java-polymorphism-my-teacher-claims-you-can-distribute-an-executable-object-thr

Comment: That is exactly my situation, Reading this article http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/sockets/  I believed I was heading in the right direction, "Using this technique, you only need to provide copies of the interface to the client and server, but not implementation" but know I will look for a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to serialize and deserialize objects with objectinput/outputstream the classes must implement Serializable.

Also the deserializer must be able to find the classes on the classpath that you are trying to deserialize since this is embedded in the Serialized form.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the client to have only the interface -- at compile time -- then you'll need to download the actual class from the server at run-time.

[Jini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jini) (aka Apache River) makes this easy.

Comment: My goal is to develop a distributed framework where the clients can receive a class and use it to do some calculations. As this is purely a learning exercise I want to develop this myself.